# How to write ruby program that logins to a website

Tags: ruby

I have little experience in ruby language and I know it's a powerful language specifically in web programming. My questions is how can I write program that automatically log in to a website and download the daily news feeds. i.e. logging in to a forum website and downloading all the threads. Thnx

Comment: Use [Mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize).

Answer (score 6):

For tasks like these that simulate a web browser experience, I use the [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) gem. It works like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

www = Mechanize.new
www.get('http://your.site/path/to/login/page') do |login_page|
    inside_page = login_page.form_with(:action => '/path/to/login/form/action') do |f|
        f.form_username_element_name = "username"
        f.form_password_element_name = "password"
    end.click_button

    # Do stuff with "inside_page", like navigate, scrape links, etc...
    # See the mechanize docs for details
end
```